# How to get bounds of 'fullscreen' UITableView before content is loaded

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've been trying to implement an overlaying activity indicator for a UITableView by this tutorial - http://www.markbetz.net/2010/09/30/ios-diary-showing-an-activity-spinner-over-a-uitableview/

It might be a little old but it seems to work well apart from a little issue with the bounds to display the overlay in.

I try to get those bounds here:

```
-(void)showActivityView {
    if (overlayController == nil) {
        // This is where I get the wrong bounds
        overlayController = [[ActivityOverlayController alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
    }
    [self.tableView insertSubview:overlayController.view aboveSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

And this gets the bounds and displays my overlay perfectly if I call the method AFTER the table is loaded and filled but if I call it before it gets wrong bounds. I've tried getting the bounds of the tableView.superView but this just displays the overlay in the top left corner.

I understand this is because the UITableView doesn't contain any cells before loading and so doesn't have proper bounds yet but I don't know of a way to get these.

Wrong display:

[image]

Correct (but after loading table) display:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about using the UITableView's "frame" property, rather than "bounds"? If the Table View is defined in a XIB, the frame should already be fine before loading cells into the table. So you would need to replace:

```
    overlayController = [[ActivityOverlayController alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
```

with:

```
    overlayController = [[ActivityOverlayController alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
```

Comment: This displays the same as my first screenshot but with a little spacing at the top. I'm using storyboard, but it's defined in there with content as dynamic prototypes

Comment: Why not place the activity indicator over the whole view, or better yet over the application's keyWindow? I would recommend using an element such as MBProgressHUD - it looks great, it's easy to use and it just works.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting MBProgressHUD, it looks better and is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

According to the example link you should do

```
-(void)showActivityView {
    if (overlayController == nil) {
        // This is where I get the wrong bounds
        overlayController = [[ActivityOverlayController alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.superview.bounds];
    }
    [self.tableView.superview insertSubview:overlayController.view aboveSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

Why are you doing `[self.tableView insertSubview:..]` instead of `[self.tableView.superview insertSubview:..]`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction. This gave me better results then with superview (superview didn't work either). I thought it was because the example worked with a .xib that had a tableview in another view and I was working with a tableviewcontroller inside the storyboard. I'm going for a different method (more userfriendly) to show loading now anyway. Thanks for trying to help though!